# Which homotopy colimits commute with finite homotopy limits?

Tags: homotopy-theory

Which homotopy colimits commute with homotopy pullbacks in the derived category $\mathcal{D}(\text{Top})$?

I was hoping there would be a theorem along the lines of it being the filtered ones. Or maybe there is something subtle to say here about how $\mathcal{D}(-)$ not commuting with one or another construction...